# strokestyle and strokewidth property not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fabricjs

i want to give strokeStyle and strokewidth properties .

i am trying examples from http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2/#text , but i am not able to see on any effect on my screen ??

Fiddle :: http://jsfiddle.net/gvn3X/1/

```
var textWithStroke = new fabric.Text("Text with a stroke", {
  strokeStyle: '#ff1318',
  strokeWidth: 1
});
var loremIpsumDolor = new fabric.Text("Lorem ipsum dolor", {
  fontFamily: 'Impact',
  strokeStyle: '#c3bfbf',
  strokeWidth: 3
});
```

Comment: Updated issue on github to update tutorial: https://github.com/kangax/fabricjs.com/issues/22

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a mistake there in that documentation or may be that syntax has been changed,
Try this code, I have tested it.. it works..

```
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  var text = new fabric.Text('Sample', {
 left: 100,
top: 100,
fill: 'navy',

 stroke: '#c3bfbf',
  strokeWidth: 3
 });
 var textWithStroke = new fabric.Text("Text with a stroke", {
 fontFamily: 'Impact',
  stroke: '#333',
   strokeWidth: 3,
   });
  canvas.add(text);
 canvas.add(textWithStroke);
```